# Is there any other Method other than pushscreen to go to next Screen?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to show another screen, when the user clicks in a ListField.

But my class containing ListField extends MainScreen!

How can I push to another screen?

Is there any way other than pushScreen to go to another screen?

Comment: you can push a MainScreen on top of a MainScreen. Why don't you want to use pushScreen?

Answer (score -1):

OverRide NavigationClick ,below is the example

```
public boolean navigationClick(int status,int time){
    Field focus = _countries.getLeafFieldWithFocus();
    if(focus instanceof ListField){
        ListField listField = (ListField)focus;
        country = listField.getCallback().get(listField,listField.getSelectedIndex()).toString();//this will return the text clicked from the listfield

    TransitionContext transition = new TransitionContext(TransitionContext.TRANSITION_FADE);
    transition.setIntAttribute(TransitionContext.ATTR_DURATION,500);
    transition.setIntAttribute(TransitionContext.ATTR_DIRECTION,TransitionContext.DIRECTION_DOWN);
    transition.setIntAttribute(TransitionContext.ATTR_STYLE,TransitionContext.STYLE_PUSH);

    UiEngineInstance engine = Ui.getUiEngineInstance();
    engine.setTransition(MyApp.scr,MyScreen._radio,UiEngineInstance.TRIGGER_PUSH,transition);
    MyApp.scr=null;
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(MyScreen._radio);
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: This is the only way to push another screen on ListField item click, nobody has a magic wand here.....